# How to reduce Samba CPU usage on CentOS server?

Tags: centos, samba, network-share

We run a small CentOS server as a test environment with staff connecting to it via Samba shares (from a combination of Macs and PCs).

The smbd service is utilising 5-10% CPU **per** user - which seems excessive. Especially as the server is a new quad-core.

Mac users seem to be causing higher CPU loads (closer to 10%) and having more problems with connection speed.

Are there any setting or configuration changes that can be made to lower CPU (and hopefully speed up connection for the Macs)

**Contents of /etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
# Global Parameters
[global]
        workgroup = Foo
        netbios name = Bar
;       encrypt passwords = yes
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536

[websites]
        path = /var/www/sites
;       browseable = yes
        write list = foobar, barfoo
;       writeable = no
        valid users = foobar, barfoo
```

Comment: What kind of traffic are you seeing from an OSX host versus a Windows host?

Comment: @mbrownnyc - it's anecdotal I'm afraid. We did use the Samba share to copy about 80gig from the Mac -> Samba -> PC and the PC was downloading at about 4 times the speed the Mac was uploading at.

Comment: yeah macs dont appear to play very well with windows servers and i dont know why, i thought they may have fixed it in 10.7 (Lion) but the problems persist. random delays on authentication and share list requests... slow performance... ect...

Comment: @Silverfire: I have the opposite anecdote; one or two macs will happily saturate Gigabit ethernet, while most (but not all) windows configs seem hardcoded at 10MB/s ('fast ethernet'?).  I don't care much since windows here are for word/excel/email and macs are for big files; still seems weird.  Except when I used 3Com switches, as soon as I plugged a mac on one of these, everything dropped to less than 1Mbps.  3Com people insisted that macs were doing "non-standard packets"; of course we haven't bought any 3Com product since.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the `wait` time?  what does `iostat` say?  If your have a storage bottleneck, it sometimes appear as high CPU usage.

I have a busy fileserver with Samba for 30-50 simultaneous Mac clients (all with Gigabit Ethernet, working with huge Photoshop files) on a modest dual core CPU.  The biggest factor was RAM (for cache).  Each time the number or workload of users increased, I added some extra RAM, and the CPU usage, as reported from most tools decreased dramatically and responsivity stayed high.

Comment: Hi Javier. Thank you for that. I now have `iostat` installed on our system. Should I try some heavy disc read/ writes while running it?

Comment: runt `iostat -x 1` and try whatever it makes it feel sluggish.  check if any column changes significantly from the 'quiet' state.  especially telling are the await, svctm and %util

Answer (score 0):

If there is another Domain Controller, add/edit the following parameters in `/etc/smb.conf`:

```
domain master = no
local master = no
preferred master = no
os level = 0
```

to make Samba never becomes a master browser. Restart Samba to see if it help.

Comment: It's a standalone server sitting outside of a domain.

Comment: Feel free to try this.